# Как скомпилировать код на Си с ассемблерными вставками? ambiguous operand size for и invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic

Tags: c, ассемблер

```
short int as (char x, short int y, char z)
{
    short int v_as=0;
    asm (
    ".intel_syntax noprefix; "
    "mov al,z    ;"
    "cbw         ;"
    "sub a, 4    ;"
    "imul y      ;"
    "mov bx, ax  ;"
    "mov al, x   ;"
    "cbw         ;"
    "add bx, ax  ;"
    "adc dx, 0   ;"
    ";Вычисление знаменателя"
    "imul 7      ;"
    "mov cx, 1   ;"
    "idiv cx     ;"
    "sub ax, 6   ;"
    ";Деление"
    "mov ax, cx  ;"
    "mov bx, ax  ;"
    "idiv cx     ;"
    "dec ax      ;"
    ";Получение результата из Ассемблера- v_as"
    "mov v_as, ax    ;"
    ".att_syntax; "
    ); //конец ассемблерной вставки

}
```

Код выдает ошибки "ambiguous operand size for `sub'" и "invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic". если это важно, то компилятор просто gcc обычный...

Comment: В `sub a, 4` a - это что, где оно у вас объявлено?

Comment: По поводу второй ошибки - попробуйте убрать комментарии на русском из ассемблерной вставки.

Comment: по моему просто забыли добавить перенос строки  `\n` после каждой команды

Comment: У вас для компилятора все "слиплось" ;) Вот пример кода с использованием Ассемблера. (Сорян, тут всё тоже слипается в комменте)

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c;
    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
        "mov eax, %1\n\t"
        "add eax, %2\n\t"
        "mov %0, eax\n\t"
        :"=r"(c)
        :"r"(a), "r"(b)
        : "eax"
    );
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}